# How to run Laravel project from remote repo

Tags: laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

we have a school project in Laravel. The setup and installation was done on my classmate's PC. But we also need it to run on my PC, but we are stuck on `composer install`. So here's what I did so far:

1. install Ubuntu WSL, create new user, install composer and PHP8.1 with all the necessary modules stated in Laravel docs (ctype, curl, mbstring, zip...)
2. cd to the folder where the repo is cloned
3. run `composer install`

output looks like this:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 37 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading doctrine/deprecations (v1.0.0)
  - Downloading doctrine/lexer (2.1.0)
  - Downloading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.0.2)
  - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v6.0.20)

...
info about the 37 packages
...

  - Installing doctrine/deprecations (v1.0.0): Extracting archive
    Install of doctrine/deprecations failed
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (2.1.0): Extracting archive
    Install of doctrine/lexer failed
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.0.2): Extracting archive
    Install of symfony/deprecation-contracts failed

...
This same fail message for all 37 packages
...
```

I've also tried `composer update` with the same result.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention these 2 errors right under 37 fail messages

```
In ZipDownloader.php line 223:

  The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesys
  tems): ZipArchive::extractTo(/mnt/c/Users/misop/Documents/Skola/bc6/webte/final/webte2_final/vendor/composer/26ae2e
  4d/doctrine-deprecations-0e2a4f1/LICENSE): Operation failed: Operation not permitted


In ZipDownloader.php line 210:

  ZipArchive::extractTo(/mnt/c/Users/misop/Documents/Skola/bc6/webte/final/webte2_final/vendor/composer/26ae2e4d/doct
  rine-deprecations-0e2a4f1/LICENSE): Operation failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: The issue is that you are using `/mnt/c`, you should be using a local folder relative to WSL, for example `/home/YOURUSER/laravel_example`. That will make it work. Have in mind that using `/mnt/c` is super slow for WSL, and you also will have permissions issues like you are having now.